# LibreOffice Calc cell worksheet references that also work in Excel?

Tags: excel, cells, worksheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet that I want to access both via LibreOffice Calc and Excel. I save the spreadsheet as an **.xls** file, and most of it works identically when I open it under either of these two programs.

However, if I want a formula that references cell "A1" on worksheet "XYZ", I have to code it as ***=XYZ!A1*** in Excel and as ***=XYZ.A1*** in LibreOffice Calc.

This prevents me from using such worksheet references in any spreadsheet that I want to access both in LibreOffice Calc and in Excel.

Does anyone know of a way to encode cell sheet references that will work both in LibreOffice Calc and Excel?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in LibreOffice Calc 4.4 / Excel 2007 running on a Windows machine.  I created the file in LO; named a sheet XYZ and, on another sheet, entered =XYZ!A1.  I saved it as an xls file.  I was able to open it in either Excel or LO, and the reference remained unchanged.  As a matter of fact, entering =XYZ.A1 in LOcalc returned a #NAME error

Comment: I'm using LOCalc 5.0 under Linux, and the "!" separator doesn't work for sheet cell refs. I have to use ".", or else I get a #NAME? error in LOCalc. I had the same problem under LOCalc 4.x. Could this be related to some Linux-versus-Windows issue, perhaps?

Comment: It seems that might be the case.  Perhaps add a Linux tag to your question, and clarify the OS's you are using, might return some more useful information.

Comment: I figured it out! It's a setting:  **Tools->Options->Libreoffice Calc->Formula->Formula Options->Formula Syntax**.  I just need to select "Excel A1" as the formula syntax, and then "!" becomes the separator.

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  That option is present in LO4.4 also.  You should post that finding as an answer, and mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

The separator for sheet/cell refs is controlled by a setting:

**Tools->Options->Libreoffice Calc->Formula->Formula Options->Formula Syntax**. I just need to select "Excel A1" as the formula syntax, and then "!" becomes the separator.

This allows sheet cell refs to work between both platforms.